# Find semi-colon character with lsearch

Tags: tcl

I have a list like so:

```
puts $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin)
VDD { POLYGON -17.4000 233.0160 -42.0000 257.6160} { -42.0000 292.4160 -17.4000 317.0160} { 17.4000 317.0160 42.0000 292.4160} { 42.0000 257.6160 17.4000 233.0160 ;} { POLYGON 132.6000 233.0160 108.0000 257.6160} { 108.0000 292.4160 132.6000 317.0160} { 167.4000 317.0160 192.0000 292.4160} { 192.0000 257.6160 167.4000 233.0160 ;} { POLYGON 282.6000 233.0160 258.0000 257.6160} { 258.0000 292.4160 282.6000 317.0160} { 317.4000 317.0160 342.0000 292.4160} { 342.0000 257.6160 317.4000 233.0160 ;} { POLYGON 432.6000 233.0160 408.0000 257.6160} { 408.0000 292.4160 432.6000 317.0160} { 467.4000 317.0160 492.0000 292.4160} { 492.0000 257.6160 467.4000 233.0160 ;} { POLYGON 582.6000 233.0160 558.0000 257.6160} { 558.0000 292.4160 582.6000 317.0160} { 617.4000 317.0160 642.0000 292.4160} { 642.0000 257.6160 617.4000 233.0160 ;} { POLYGON 732.6000 233.0160 708.0000 257.6160} { 708.0000 292.4160 732.6000 317.0160} { 767.4000 317.0160 792.0000 292.4160} { 792.0000 257.6160 767.4000 233.0160 ;} { POLYGON 882.6000 233.0160 858.0000 257.6160} { 858.0000 292.4160 882.6000 317.0160} { 917.4000 317.0160 942.0000 292.4160} { 942.0000 257.6160 917.4000 233.0160 ;}
```

and I want to search for the list indices of the entries with a semi-colon charatcer.

For example `lsearch -index 0 -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) POLYGON` gives me

> 1 5 9 13 17 21 25

But `lsearch -index 0 -regexp -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) [;]` gets me

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

So actually I need some escaping or something. But I tried various things. Not working:

```
lsearch -index 0 -regexp -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) {;}
lsearch -index 0 -regexp -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) [;]
lsearch -index 0 -regexp -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) ";"
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
lsearch -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) "*;*"
```

This is a `glob` / text match search for a semicolon anywhere within an item in the list.

If you only want the items that have a semicolon as a last element (which is the same as all items with a semicolon in the example data), you could specify it:

```
lsearch -all -index end $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) ";"
```

You still need to escape the semicolon (as `";"`, `{;}`, or `\;`) since it is command separator in the command line.

Your attempts failed for a couple of reasons. For one thing, you were looking in the first element of each item, while all the semicolons were the last element. For another, the value of `[;]` is the empty string (setting the search mode to `-regexp` only influences how the command handles the arguments internally, not how they are interpreted in the command line).

Comment: lsearch -index 0 -glob -all $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) "*;*"
gives me an empty string
Wichtout -index 0 I get the expected result. Why do I need it for the first example?

Comment: @erdin.sinanovic`-index id` is used when you are dealing with list of lists, it will look at only the `id`th element of the sub-list in the list. So in your big list `$macro_info($macro,pins,$pin)`, in the sub-list for example `{ 942.0000 257.6160 917.4000 233.0160 ;}`, `lsearch -index 0` will only look for `;` within `942.0000`. If it was `lsearch -index 1`, it would look only within `257.6160`. Does it make sense?

Comment: That's how I also understood it. But somehow without the option, the first searh didn't suceed... But now it works.... Maybe it's too late and I should go home =) ! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @erdin.sinanovic: you need `-index 0` for the first search because the key `POLYGON` only has matches in the first element of the items.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample input the semicolon is always the last element of the sublists. In that special case you can use:

```
lsearch -all -index end $macro_info($macro,pins,$pin) {;}
```